# Am I using the 2D Arraylist length function right?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, dynamic

The error I am getting: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 11 out of bounds for length 6`

In the project I have to do I have to be able to add and delete from a table certain values which completely work. However I want to make my 2D `ArrayList` able to have a set value of 6 (width) and 6 (length) but be able to add objects out of range, example `addToTable(x, y) - > addToTable(7, 7)` without it erroring.

variable:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<My2DTableCoordinate>> coordinates
```

function:

```
private boolean checkIfInRange(int x, int y) {
    if (x < coordinates.get(x).size() && y < coordinates.get(y).size()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

this is given that

```
  int width = 6;
  int height = 6;
```

`x` being width, `y` being height

Comment: You are not able to add objects past what the array length is set to when initialized. To do what you want, you could create a second array, with a length and width of 7 instead.

Comment: would there be a way i could have a hard coded 2d arraylist but be able to add dynamic x and y variables to that arraylist? @CodingShark

Comment: I think the closest you could get to a dynamic array, is like you posted, using an arrayList, and resizing the array if you need to add more items. Is that close enough to what you need? Just do a google search on resizing an arrayList if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Apache Commons Collection Utils. The Types `GrowthList` and `LazyList` can be a solution for your problem. Here are the links to the javadoc:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/collections4/list/GrowthList.html

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/collections4/list/LazyList.html